# Error: We encountered an internal error. Please try again

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In a script I have been successfully executing hundreds of **aws s3 mv commands** per day when suddenly got the following error:

```
move failed
Error: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: If that error came from S3 then raise a support case with AWS, including the API request ID. Also, did you try again? Did it work later?

Comment: yes the error came from using the aws cli for s3 and yes it did work later.

Comment: Not sure what the underlying error is but for the sake of resilience you might want to wrap the awscli call in a loop so that you can retry it a few times if it fails, with an appropriate delay between each invocation.